# Pattern searching using regular expression in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm new to DB development. I have a new assignment.
I need to find a pattern starting from `13xxxxx` from a column which has data as below:

```
["1301800-" "1321002-" "1202038-" "1201505-[\"32909062963\"]"]
```

Tried to use regular expression, but I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt. And add some more sample data and also the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: The question is not that clear. [mcve] could be useful to edit your question, clarify it and get some help. As is, it's really hard to understand what logic you need to implement.

Comment: Data is as below in the column:

Comment: It;s a shame your deadline is so pressing you don't have the time to frame a proper question. Explaining your problem clearly increases your chances of getting the help you need. For instance, showing what "the desired result" looks like.

Comment: Hi Pramoddt. If experienced users make a change to your post (e.g. grammar or formatting) then please leave it be. Unless an edit was incorrect (e.g. substantially changes meaning), rollbacks are regarded as vandalism here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regexp which might do what you want: `'"13[0-9]{5}\-?'` . It matches seven digit numbers starting with 13 and with an optional trailing minus sign.

This example trims the leading `"` for tidiness:

```
SQL> with dta as
  2    ( select '["1301800-" "1321002-" "1202038-" "1201505-[\"32909062963\"]"]' str
  3      from dual )
  4  select trim('"' from
  5              regexp_substr(str, '"13[0-9]{5}\-?', 1, level)
  6            ) as tkn
  7  from dta
  8  connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '"13[0-9]{5}\-?')
  9  /

TKN
----------
1301800-
1321002-

SQL>
```